# Is there any way to chart/graph/map or otherwise visualize the interrelations of sagas?

Tags: javascript, redux, visualization, redux-saga, static-analysis

We have a project with a bunch of sagas produced with [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/).

I wonder if there's any way to visualize the possible flows between these sagas to produce a comprehensive map of our sagas and how they interrelate?

The rationale for this is that such a graph could lead to better long term design of our saga structure, and possibly we could have one or two sagas which are redundant.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not the exact answer you're looking for:

Honestly, I can't think of ever seeing something like this.  At most there's the couple WIP "saga devtools" packages I've seen (like https://github.com/abettadapur/redux-saga-devtools-extension and https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga-devtools ), but I don't think either of those is complete or what you're really asking for.

Beyond that: our general advice for the last few years has been to *avoid* using sagas for most use cases, and doubly so if you're using them for basic data fetching.

Today, RTK Query solves the data fetching use case, thunks do most other work, and the new RTK "listener" middleware solves the "run logic in response to actions" use case with a smaller bundle size, simpler API, and better TS support.

For more details, see my recent talk "The Evolution of Redux Async Logic":

- https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/05/presentations-evolution-redux-async-logic/